# find BSSID in PHP or JavaScript

Tags: php, bssid

How can I find **BSSID** or MAC adress in PHP or JavaScript? Sorry for my english, but I'm from Czech Repulic and I speak english a little bit.

Comment: BSSID of what do you need to find?

Comment: BSSID of client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is a server side language, and it doesn't know much about the client, except for the [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variable, for example.

Javascript can be executed in browser on the client side, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388538/can-i-find-the-bssid-mac-address-of-a-wireless-access-point-from-an-http-reque) it is still not possible without additional plugins.